# In JavaScript, is there any difference between typeof x == 'y' and typeof x === 'y'?

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison, undefined, typeof

I'm aware of the difference between strict and loose comparison operators. Clearly `x == y` is different from `x === y`. But whenever I see code that uses `typeof`, it always uses `===`.

If the `typeof` operator always evaluates to a string (such as 'boolean', 'number', etc.), then wouldn't `typeof x == 'y'` and `typeof x === 'y'` always render the same result? And if so, why the use of `===`?

I know it's faster doing strict comparisons, but except in extreme cases, the performance gain should be imperceptible. Another idea is that it's just clearer to always use `===` since it *does* cause issues with *similar* operations like `x == undefined` versus `x === undefined`. Is it worthwhile to reduce these cases to `==` to improve minification and transfer encoding, or is it better to keep `===` to maintain runtime performance and general clarity?

Comment: Generally it's best practice to use strict comparison to avoid problems with loose comparison. Besides, an extra `=` is nothing compared to potentially brittle code.

Comment: The performance gain should be imperceptible, but the penalty in minification as well, so I would choose the nicest/cleanest option, which in my opinion is to use strict operators wherever possible.

Comment: Since you have `performance` tagged, then your answer is [not really](http://jsperf.com/typeof-strictness).

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer That makes sense. Though if the result for `typeof` is always identical either way, and if a programmer is smart enough to know the difference between `=`, `==`, `===`, `typeof`, `null`, `undefined`, etc., then I'm wondering how much of an issue it really is. Either way, it seems the consensus is to just always use `===` unless otherwise needed.

Comment: @Qix Thanks; I was worried the question might get flagged since there are so many others out there about comparison operators. This one is specifically about `typeof` and my confusion over never seeing it with a loose comparison.

Comment: If you are gzipping your .js files, and [you should be](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/08/13/), I'm betting consistently using `===` will produce smaller files than using both `===` and `==`.

Comment: @UselessCode Great point; I never thought of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes absolutely no useful difference either way in this case.

> The **typeof** operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

We know it is always going to be a string, and it will only be that of a few predefined values, so there is no **explicit** reason to use the strict operator when comparing the results of typeof, however the strict comparison operator should be used for readability, and to avoid **any** possible exceptions to that statement.

**But**

> **Loose equality using ==**
>   Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both values to a common type.

That being said it should be marginally faster to use the strict comparison as there is no conversion, but the difference is so small that it doesn't matter, and [micro optimizing is a very bad thing](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

---

**Edit**

According to the documentation [11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) and [11.9.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) if they are the same type there should be no difference.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80469/discussion-on-answer-by-humble-rumble-in-javascript-is-there-any-difference-bet).